# Removing duplicates of same date and location (3 columns) in R

Tags: r, duplicates

I know there are like a million questions regarding duplicate removal, but unfortunately
none of them helped me so far. I struggle with the following:

I have a data frame (loc) that includes data of citizen science observations of nature (animals, plants, etc.). It has about 90.000 rows and looks like this:

```
      ID      Datum      lat     long      Anzahl        Art         Gruppe    Anrede Wochentag
1 1665376475 2019-05-09 51.30993 9.319896     20 Alytes obstetricans Amphibien   Herr        Do
2  529728479 2019-05-06 50.58524 8.503332      1 Alytes obstetricans Amphibien   Frau        Mo
3 1579862637 2019-05-23 50.53925 8.467546      8 Alytes obstetricans Amphibien   Herr        Do
4 -415013306 2019-05-06 50.58524 8.503332      3 Alytes obstetricans Amphibien   Frau        Mo
```

I also made a small sample data frame (loc_sample) of 10 observations and used dput(loc_sample):

```
  structure(list(ID = c(688380991L, -1207894879L, 802295973L, -815104336L, -632066829L, -133354744L, 1929856503L, 952982037L, 1782222413L, 1967897802L), 
  Datum = structure(c(1559088000, 1558742400, 1557619200, 1557273600, 1557187200, 1557619200, 1557619200, 1557187200, 1557964800, 1556841600), 
  tzone = "UTC", 
  class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
  lat = c(52.1236088700115, 51.5928822313012, 53.723426877949, 50.7737623304861, 49.9238597947287, 51.805563222817, 50.1738326622472, 51.2763067511127, 51.395189306337, 51.5732959108075), 
  long = c(8.62399927116144, 9.89597797393799, 9.04058595819038, 8.20740532922287, 8.29073164862348, 9.9225640296936, 8.79065646492143, 6.40700340270996, 6.47360801696777, 6.25690012620748), 
  Anzahl = c(2L, 25L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 30L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
  Art = c("Sturnus vulgaris", "Olethreutes arcuella", "Sylvia atricapilla", "Buteo buteo", "Turdus merula", "Orchis mascula subsp. mascula", "Parus major", "Luscinia megarhynchos", "Milvus migrans", "Andrena bicolor"), 
 Gruppe = c("Voegel", "Schmetterlinge", "Voegel", "Voegel", "Voegel", "Pflanzen", "Voegel", "Voegel", "Voegel", "InsektenSonstige"), 
 Anrede = c("Herr", "Herr", "Frau", "Herr", "Herr", "Herr", "Herr", "Herr", "Herr", "Herr"), 
 Wochentag = structure(c(4L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 6L), 
 .Label = c("So", "Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa"), 
 class = c("ordered", "factor"))), 
 row.names = c(NA, -10L), 
 class = "data.frame")
```

For my question only the variables `Datum`, `lat`and `long` are important. Datum is a date and in the POSIXct format while lat and long are both numeric. There are quite a few observations that were reported on the same day from the exact same location. I would like to filter and remove those. So I have to check three separate columns and keep only one of each "same-place-same-day" observations.

I already tried putting the three variables in question into one:

```
  loc$dupl <- paste(loc$Datum, loc$lat, loc$long, sep=" ,")
  locu <- unique(loc[,2:4])
```

It seems like I managed to filter the duplicates, but I'm actually not sure, if that's how it is done correctly.

Also, that gives me a data frame with only `Datum`, `lat` and `long`. As a final result I need the original data frame without the duplicates in date and location, but with all the other information for the unique rows still left.
When I try:

```
 locu <- unique(loc[,2:9])
```

It gives me all the other columns, but it doesn't remove the date and location duplicates.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Change the `locu <- unique(loc[,2:3:4])` part to `locu <- unique(loc[,2:4])` (but this won't solve your problem)

Comment: I see what I did wrong there and edited the post, but it like you said...it doesn't really solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can work:

```
#Code
new <- loc[!duplicated(paste(loc$Datum,loc$lat,loc$long)),]
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the full data frame back after finding the duplicates, you coudl do sth. like:

```
loc[!duplicated(loc[,2:4]),]
```

This code first detects the duplicate rows and then subsets your original data frame.

Note: this code will always keep the first occurences and delete the duplicates in subsequent rows. If you want to keep a certain ID (e.g. the second one, not the first one), we need a different solution.

Comment: The command doesn't really do anything to be honest. I don't know why, but no rows are removed.

Comment: Please share a minimal reporducible example of your data: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. It works just fine for me.

Comment: I added a dput(). When I use your command it just removes the first row for some reason. Nothing about the duplicates changes...

Comment: `loc[!duplicated(loc[,2:4]),]` works fine.

Comment: Editted my post accordingly.